# MYSQL: select records with lowest sort

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
ID | product | image | sort
---------------------------
1  |   1     |  img1 |  1
2  |   1     |  img2 |  1
3  |   1     |  img3 |  2
4  |   2     |  img4 |  1
5  |   2     |  img5 |  2
```

how can I select the records with lowest sort and lowest id grouping by product?

the result that I would like to get is the following:

```
ID | product | image | sort
---------------------------
1  |   1     |  img1 |  1
4  |   2     |  img4 |  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * from table WHERE = (Select MIN(sort) from table) ORDER BY ID ASC group by product
```